# Создать словарь из DataFrame со средним значением

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, данные

Есть список состоящий из двух колонок. Необходимо создать из него словарь по такому принципу: для каждого значения комнат определить среднее значение площади.

Делал через поиск среднего значения для каждого типа комнат, но код получается большой, необходимо модифицировать.

Список должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
dict_rooms = {  
        0: 18.0,
        1: 17.4,
        2: 30.0}
```

Пример дата фрейма

```
rooms   area
1   16
0   20
3   21
0   24
0   4
2   32
4   45
2   50
5   60
5   30
5   20
3   240
2   33
2   20
1   110
1   23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = df.groupby(“rooms”)[“area”].mean()
```

Comment: спасибо все сработало